# "Move folders only if they exist" not working

Tags: bash, shell-script, debian

i am trying to move folders to a different directory only if they exist. I tried this

```
project_dir="/home/user/Desktop/Code/projectX"
public_folders=(css sass js vendor)

for item in "${public_folders[@]}"; 
do
  [ ! -f "$item" ] || mv -v "$item" "$project_dir"/public/"$item"
done
```

but the folders are not moved when i run the script. What's the issue?

Comment: a bash array should be defined like: `public_folders=(css sass js vendor)` no commas. Also quote the variables later (and always).

Comment: Please use a shell checker, like this: https://www.shellcheck.net/ and you will be guided for how to fix the syntax.

Comment: @thanasisp i just solved all those issues and the folders are still not moved . hmm

Comment: Then, [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/701071/edit) the question to update the existing script with your changes.

Comment: @thanasisp code updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your test does the opposite of what you want it to.

```
[ ! -f $item ] || mv -v $item $project_dir/public/$item
```

The `!` in combination with `||` make this effectively the same as `[ -f $item ] && ...`.

i.e. you're testing if `$item` is a regular file, and `mv`-ing it if it is.  A directory will never return true to that test, because it's not a regular file, it's a directory.  You should be testing if it is a directory, with `-d` rather than `-f`.

Instead, do this (remember to double-quote your variables too):

```
[ -d "$item" ] && mv -v "$item" "$project_dir/public/"
```

---

BTW, even using `[ ! -f "$item" ] && mv ...` would be incorrect because directories aren't the only "files" that aren't **regular files** - on Linux, there are also, block device nodes, character device nodes, sockets, named pipes, and symbolic links.  See [Unix file types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_file_types)

Comment: Thanks, this solved the issue.